# PHP Today's date in form

Tags: php, date

I've got several text boxes in a form that are the input to a SQL query.
I need one of the boxes to auto populate with today's date but can't get it to work :

```
  <td align="left"><INPUT TYPE="text" MAXLENGTH="10" SIZE="10" NAME="To_Date" id=To_Date value="'.date("m/d/y").'"/></td>
```

displays the following in the text box:

'.date(

Help is much appreciated!

Cheers,

Rene

Comment: You're mixing PHP code and HTML... Without letting the parser know it's PHP. So, it's treated as HTML.

Comment: And just to be pedantic, don't write HTML Tags in uppercase, makes me cringe like I'm back in 1998 :|

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try with either one like

**PHP in HTML :**

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo date('m/d/y');?>"/>
```

**HTML in PHP :**

```
<?php echo "<input type='text' value='".date('m/d/y')."'";?>
```

Dont mesh both `PHP` and `HTML` and another is **better** to write `HTML` in lower cases.

Answer (score 1):

## 01 2022

Not sure why everyone is using `type="text"`

### Using `type="date"`

When using php date in the input date value, make sure the format is correct.
If not it will not work.

#### Works

Use the format `Y-m-d` (separted by hyphen but in reverse order)
`<input type="date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">`

#### Will not work

`d-m-Y` (using the hyphen, but placing date at the start)
`d/m/Y` (using slash)
`Y/m/d` (using slash in reverse order)

Answer (score 0):

alternatively you can use.

```
echo '<input type="text" value="'.date('m/d/y').'"/></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use PHP in a HTML tag. You have to open the `<?php` tag before writing any PHP code. So your code should be:

```
<td align="left">
     <input type="text" maxlength="10" size="10" name="To_Date" id="To_Date" value="<?php echo date("m/d/y") ?>"/>
</td>
```

PS: Conventions want to use lowercase attributes in HTML, so I transform a little your input ;) (Yours was HTML5 valid, but it's just convention, deh.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it worked for me.

```
 <input type="text" name="Date" readonly = "readonly"  value="<?php echo date('m/d/y');?>"/>
```